# Gstreamer: How is it possible to get a "no element X" error, when "gst-inspect-1.0 X" shows the element?

Tags: python, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, gobject

Does running `Gst.parse_launch()` search for plugins the same way as `gst-inspect-1.0`?

I have a python script at some point runs this:

```
pipeline_string = ... ! openh264dec ! ...
pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_string)
```

Whenever this code is reached, it returns this:

```
File "/home/myUser/myApp/main.py", line 285, in init_loop_and_pipeline
    pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_string)
gi.repository.GLib.GError: gst_parse_error: no element "openh264dec" (1)
```

If I inspect the element with `gst-inspect-1.0 openh264dec`, then I get the expected output, showing that the plugin is found and located at `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopenh264.so`.

Perhaps related: Why does `gst-inspect-1.0 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopenh264.so` work, but `cd  /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0` `gst-inspect-1.0 libgstopenh264.so` return

```
GStreamer-WARNING **: 20:47:45.546: Failed to load plugin 'libgstopenh264.so': libgstopenh264.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Could not load plugin file: Opening module failed: libgstopenh264.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Gst.parse_launch() is a binding in a python environment. gst-inspect-1.0 is using current system gstreamer install. These may be different versions. It may also be related to how you defined LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable in Linux case.